# Zener Diode for Minimum Voltage Regulator

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, diodes, zener, photoresistor

I forgot the name of it, but I remember one post where it said that you can use a zener diode as a "minimum voltage regulator". I don't think I used the right term for it, but here's what I'm doing. I'm trying to make a photoresistor turn on an infrared LED (don't ask why), and all the bells and whistles are in place... except that I don't want the LED to run at 0.001V when the teeniest of light hits the photoresistor. I also tried using a zener diode (reversed) to have everything over the LEDs operative voltage.

[image: Hey - there's a schematic]

The "Var. Resistor" represents the photoresistor. Does anyone know why the zener diode is "leaking" some current here? Also, is it right to use the zener diode like this? Please, any answers, comments, and suggestions may be useful and I appreciate all of them. Sorry for the lengthy question and the "a-hrefed" image, I don't have enough reputation to post images. Thanks!

Comment: Tell us what you are trying to achieve, not how you think it might be able to be done. | You need to decide if you are trying to learn about zeners or make a circuit do a required job. Zeners are used by the billions as voltage regulators. The LED test switch will destroy some LEDs when operated. What is the ACTUAL voltage that you have available? Zener switching is very "soft" and tends not to suit what you are trying to do. | As shown all your voltage will be dropped across the zener as Vzener = Vbattery. | Tell us what you are trying to achieve, not how yo think it might be able to be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A zener can be used as a simple voltage regulator when the voltage source has sufficiently high resistance.  This is called a "shunt regulator".  It regulates by loading the power source so that it doesn't exceed some voltage.  Shunt regulators have their purpose, but are used in special applications because they are pretty inefficient in most applications.

I took a brief look at the schematic, and there seems to be signficant confusion there.  Post it here instead of a link to make it easier to talk about.

### Added now that the schematic is more accessible:

I don't know where to begin explaining so I'll just enumerate some of the problems:

LEDs need to be driven with current, not voltage.  The current as a function of voltage is rather unpredictable near the intended operating point.  With the LED test switch closed, you are applying a fixed voltage to the LED.  That could be bad if the LED would normally operate at a little less voltage than the battery.

Since the LED requires about the same voltage as the battery, you won't get much of anything from it with a zener in series.  Even a single forward diode drop would drive the LED with so little voltage it probably wouldn't put out noticable light.  The 2.5V zener will drop all the battery voltage and leave nothing for the LED, so the LED will never come on.

You say you don't want to run the LED at 1 mV, but that won't cause any problem since it won't draw any current at that voltage.

You need to step back and explain what you are really trying to accomplish.  This circuit it too broken to bother with it as a starting point.  If you provide *clear specs* as to what you want the LED current to be as a function of the photoresistor resistance, we can probably help.  It would also help if you provided a link to the LED datasheet since 2.5V is unlikely for a IR LED.

### Added after more infomation from the OP

You now say: *I want a voltage regulator that allows current through if it is *_* volts or amps or whatever unit it uses.*

Learn the units.  That's how we communicate.  That will also force you to think more clearly.  A big part of the problem is that you are contradicting yourself, probably in part because you are using the wrong terms.  Whether you understand the terms fully or not, you can at least be careful.  Above you say *if it is* but once again it's not clear what "it" is referring to.  There is good reason we don't allow hand waving in engineering.

*I'm looking for something similar to a "crowbar" circuit.*

OK that's more clear and is what I started out thinking you were asking about but you later contradicted.  As I said originally, such things are called "shunt regulators".  A true crowbar is something else, but I don't think you mean that.  It now seems you want something that conducts no current until a voltage threshold is reached, then conducts current after that with the fixed voltage offset accross it.  That is basically what a zener diode does, and what a shunt regulator does.  A zener diode can be used as a simple shunt regulator.  More complicated shunt regulators use active electronics to make a sharper knee.

However, once again, I think you are getting bogged down in details of whatever implementation you suppose instead of the true problem.  That apparently has something to do with driving a LED a particular way depending on light level.  I asked before what the LED current was supposed to be as a function of the photoresistor value.  Since you have refused to answer that, I am giving up now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 2.5 VDC, I forgot to mention, is an example in the schematics. The purpose of this project is to find out if the zener diode can act as a voltage regulator. Given that LEDs run on current and not voltage, does this mean that I can forget about the 1mV thing (since the trickling voltage won't affect it)?

Comment: Yes, zener diodes can be used as part of a voltage regulator.  They can act as a shunt regulator directly or provide the reference for some other type of regulator.  It's not clear what this has to do with your LED though.  Again, step back two layers and explain what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: OK, so my main goal is... to create a voltage regulator to only allow electricity through if greater than _____VDC. Since you've stated that LEDs won't be affected if, like, only 0.5VDC passes through because they won't draw any current, then I guess I don't need the voltage regulator!

Comment: @Francis: This is a long way from actually answering what I asked.  You start out saying you want a *voltage regulator*, but then say you only want to let "electricity" (current?) through if "greater than" (what is greater than?) some voltage.  This makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood, but I want a voltage regulator that allows current through if it is ___ volts or amps or whatever unit it uses. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I forgot this word earlier, but please put it this way, I'm looking for something similar to a "crowbar" circuit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, Zener diodes should be thought of as devices which:

1. Are guaranteed to drop at least a certain amount of voltage if at least some particular amount of current is passing through them (but not so much as to kill the device).

   Are guaranteed to pass at most a certain amount of current when reverse-biased below some amount.

   Subject only to the above constraints, might pass through any amount of current at any voltage.

In the Falstad simulator, a Zener diode with a certain amount of voltage across it will always pass through some nice precise amount of current.  In practice, things are less predictable.  The Falstad simulator shows that a "5.1 volt" Zener will pass through 5.01uA at 4.25 volts.  In practice, a real 5.1-volt Zener diode might let through a tenth that much or ten times as much at such a voltage.  While things are slightly better characterized nearer the Zener voltage, one should probably allow for at least +/- half an order of magnitude variation in the amount of current a Zener might pass at any voltage.

Fortunately, the amount of current a 5.1-volt Zener will pass at 5.5 volts will be well over an order of magnitude higher than what it will pass at 4.7 volts.  It may well be that one Zener would pass through 3A at 5.5 volts and 30mA at 4.7 volts, while another would pass through 100mA at 5.5 volts and 1mA at 4.7 volts, but even though one part lets through 1.5 orders of magnitude more current than the other (i.e. 30 times as much), one could still build a supply that would output 5.1 volts +/- 0.4 volts at 0-70mA, by feeding 100mA into the parallel combination of the Zener diode and the load.

Comment: Thanks for the response supercat! So, does this mean that the Falstad ciruit is... inaccurate? Or am I confused here?

Comment: @Francis Lau: The Falstad simulator could be regarded as showing one way in which a Zener diode *might* behave.  If one discovers that a "5.1V" diode in the Falstad simulator drops some voltage when 10mA is put through it, and then measures a couple dozen real Zener diodes, one might find that some of them have a higher voltage drop than the simulator would suggest, and others have a lower drop.  The simulator is good for getting a general idea of how/whether a circuit might work, but not so good for showing how tolerant it will be of component variations.

Answer (score 0):

A circuit like this will switch the LED in the way you want.
 It uses the cheap and available TL431 or TLV431. Theses are shunt regulators - effectively programmable super zeners.

The TL431, transistor and LED all turn on when the sense input on the TL431 rises above the reference voltage.

Rh and Rl are either photo resistors or fixed resistors.
 If Rh = photo resistor that drops in resistance with increasing light, placin it where Rh is will turn the LED on when the light rises above a preset level. Instead replace Rl with the sensor if the LED is to turn off as light rises. etc.

TL431 switches when ref input is above 2.5V.
 TLV431 switches at 1.25V.

When TLVx431 is on the cathode drops to **about** the reference voltage.

[image]

[TL431 data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431a.pdf)
[TLV431 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv431a.pdf)

A zener diode of the correct rating could be used in place of the TLx431, but would not be as good.

Comment: `...cheap and available`... are you sure??? There's only 3 results on Google Shopping, and the lowest-priced one was US$7.56. :(

Comment: @FrancisLau -  In stock at [$US0.08/1 at digikey](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/TL431IZT/497-2228-1-ND/599206) Digikey is an excellent source in many cases. NOBODY should charge $7.56 for a TL431. Not even a gold plated one ;-). t's possibly THE cheapest IC on earth.

Comment: @Francis Lau - Google Shopping is not a good source for small electronics parts. You really need a specialty distributor for this sort of thing. digikey.com, mouser.com, newark.com, futurelec.com, sparkfun.com, and thers are all good sources for ICs and similar parts.